# C# Не удаётся неявно преобразовать тип "string" в "lab6.Chem"

Tags: c#, строки, перегрузка-операторов

Листинг класса Chem.cs

```
namespace lab6
{
    public class Chem
    {
        public string Elem_Name;
        public string Elem_Formula;
        public Chem(string elem_name, string elem_formula)
        {
            Elem_Name = elem_name;
            Elem_Formula = elem_formula;
        }

        public static Chem operator +(Chem x, Chem y)
        {
            return x.Elem_Formula + y.Elem_Formula;
        }
    }
}
```

Листинг Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var elem1 = new Chem("Углерод", "C");
        var elem2 = new Chem("Кислород", "O2");
        var elem3 = new Chem("Атом водорода", "H2");
        var elem4 = new Chem("Калий", "K");
        var elem5 = new Chem("Кальций", "Ca");
        var elem6 = new Chem("Гидроксид углерода", "2CO");
        var elem7 = new Chem("Кальций", "Ca");
        Console.WriteLine(elem6 + elem2);
    }
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку в строке `return x.Elem_Formula + y.Elem_Formula;`:

```
CS0029 Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "String" в "lab6.Chem"
```

Нужно просто чтобы программа выдала в консоли например `elem6+elem2 = 2COO2`

Answer (score 2):

Причина ошибки указана в тексте ошибки:

> Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "String" в "lab6.Chem".

Оператор + имеет возвращаемый тип `Chem`, а значит должен возвращать объект типа `Chem`. Вы же возвращаете выражение `x.Elem_Formula + y.Elem_Formula` результатом которого является строка, так как слогаемые - строки.

Есть 3 решения:

1. Поменять возвращаемый тип метода на `string` (хоть он и кажется мне логически не правильным)

```
public static string operator +(Chem x, Chem y)
{
    return x.Elem_Formula + y.Elem_Formula;
}
```

2. Складывать формулы:

```
Console.WriteLine(elem6.Elem_Formula + elem2.Elem_Formula);
```

3. Сделать сложение немного иначе, так чтобы оно создавало новую формулу:

```
public static Chem operator +(Chem x, Chem y)
{
    return new Chem(
        x.Elem_Name + " + " + y.Elem_Name,
        x.Elem_Formula + y.Elem_Formula);
}
```

И переопределить метод `ToString()` так, чтобы он выводил текст формулы:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Elem_Formula;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А что мешает перегрузить оператор сложения так, чтобы он возвращал не новый объект класса `Chem`, а строку?

```
public static string operator +(Chem x, Chem y)
{
    return x.Elem_Formula + y.Elem_Formula;
}
```